# How to define another stats file in gem5

Tags: statistics, gem5

I have defined some new statistics in gem5 in `cache/base.cc`. I want to have them in a separate file ( not necessarily in `stats.txt`). 
I defined a new file in `cache/base.hh` and used `fprintf(fptr,....)` in `regstats()` function to print it. But nothing was printed in the file.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: I'm curious why you need separate files. I don't know this part of the code exactly, but it should be very simple, have you GDB step debugged your code/existing code to compare them (+ possibly setup Eclipse to easily find definitions)?